# jquery get first td value

Tags: jquery, html

I am getting HTML Table in jQuery Ajax response

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/ajaxExecute.aspx?Fn=GETFEE',
        type: 'POST',
        context: document.body,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
});
```

response contains following table

```
 <table border="1" id="tbl1" border="0" style="margin-left:30px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>fee_type</th><th>fee_amount</th><th>from_amt</th><th>to_amt</th><th>fee_percent</th><th>higher_of_two</th><th>max_capture</th><th>min_capture</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td><td>5</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0.00</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want only first row first td value i.e. 0

```
response.find('td').html();
```

**in Console i am getting error Object response has no method 'find'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .eq selector

```
$(response).find('tbody td:eq(0)').html();
```

Comment: This is the answer you want as it'll only find the first td like you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it using jQuery to create a jQuery reference.

The value returned by the ajax request is a string which does not have the jQuery method `find()` that is the reason for the error

```
$(response).find('td').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

> Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

The ajax function returns HTML as plain text. This means you must do this :

```
$(response).find('td').html();
```